# How to add local images in azure bot framework. I am using node js

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, azure-bot-service

I have created a folder and uploaded all images in the  azure bot framework.

Now i want to use that image for the hards(Hero, Thumbnail). I am using node js. Kindly help me on the same

Comment: Please provide the code which you tried so far.I'd recommend you to see how to ask questions in SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To add a local image we have to convert that into an base64 string format.

var base64Img = require('base64-img');
var data =base64Img.base64Sync('./img/'+ predict +'.png');

***Thumbnail Card***
tilte: "title",
subtitle: 'subtitle',
text: 'text',
img:data,